# Something keeps deleting my downloaded files

Tags: macos, utorrent

I have been using uTorrent for years now and recently I was surprised that I had 24GB free. I thought that was because I deleted some unused apps, but after awhile, I noticed my Torrents folder was gone (I put finished torrents in my Downloads/Torrents folder).

I thought I accidentally deleted it (I use `rm -r` to delete huge files) so I shrugged and tried to download those 24GB back (after banging my head for the sheer stupidity).

This morning, I noticed that again, my Torrent folder was gone! This made me think that something MUST be deleting my torrent files. I am not sure but my hunch is uTorrent (so I just upgraded it) or something else entirely. This is getting frustrating, so I hope someone can help me on this.

My only guess is when I do <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (I'm on a Mac, OSX Lion), it closes the window and somehow deletes the torrents? I am downloading files again now and will try to document what I do the tomorrow so I can add more input here.

Comment: If I remember correctly, if you select the default "Remove" action in µTorrent to remove a (possibly finished) torrent from the list, it deletes the associated data as well. The paramter `gui.default_del_action` controls this behavior.

Comment: where do i set that parameter?

Comment: also i didnt "remove" any torrent. i tend to keep all my torrents to seed them. i discovered they were gone when i turned on utorrent and all of my torrents had red exclamation marks beside them, meaning the files were gone

Comment: [This is where you can set the parameter](http://i.imgur.com/7YSKS.png), but given your update, I doubt it'll have any impact on your issue.

Comment: oh sorry, i am on OSX lion...looks like this is a windows screen. it doesn't show any of those in my preferences window

Comment: Which part of the given answer solved this?

Comment: i might have inadvertently modified the remove setting or i may have accidentally cmd + deleted the torrents instead of just doing delete(delete takes it out of the torrent list hile cmd + delete deletes the torrent along with the downloaded file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two likely explanations:

- You have inadvertently modified the remove setting as Oliver said. Right-click the *Remove* button in the toolbar and set it to just `Remove`:

  [image]
- You have inadvertently modified the *completed-torrent* directory (maybe you set it to the temp folder or another drive):

  [image]

Comment: OMG this bugged the hell out of me. I've never touched it and yet it had been changed to on somehow... On Windows

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your antivirus software - it may be quietly deleting any downloads that it detects as malware and placing them in quarantine.